# What is the most "compatible" way of autoplaying sound?

Tags: html, audio, cross-browser

I want to add a sound in my page that autoplays but it seems like all ways require some plugin or codex or idk so I'm not quite sure what is the best audio format and way to code it so it works for most users and browsers.

Is there some way to works for most people?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `BGSOUND` tag like this :

```
<BGSOUND SRC="waitng2.wav" LOOP="2">
```

but only accepts `WAV` and `MID` formats.

for `MP3` formats you can use `EMBED` tag but in some browser need plugin to be played.

```
<embed src="http://www.davesite.com/webstation/html/davesite.mp3" 
   loop="true" autoplay="false" width="145" height="60"></embed>
```

you can also use compination of these two ways to correct compatablity problem:

```
<NOEMBED><BGSOUND SRC="waitng2.wav" LOOP="2"></NOEMBED>
<EMBED SRC="waitng2.mp3" HEIGHT="0" WIDTH="0" AUTOSTART="TRUE"></EMBED>
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work in firefox. I tried the three codes. I can't make anything work in firefox. I'm using Chrome too and it autoplays with no problems

Comment: Firefox 4. I'm in Ubuntu, I don't think that has anything to do it but I'll test it later in windows. Thanks

Comment: I didn't get around to test it on windows, but everyone says this is the correct approach