# Playing audio file in client side in Asp.net

Tags: html

I want to play a media file in client side using Asp.net,Please tell me the code for that.I have implemented it in server side but when I uploaded my site the server does not support this feature.Please tell me the code where I can execute it in client side.

Also do tell me the plugin required to execute that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this :

[What is the most "compatible" way of autoplaying sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775832/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-of-autoplaying-sound/5775984#5775984)

This needs no plugin or other add-on on your clients.

Comment: Thanks farzin but they are not working can yo give me the example of code of page as I am new to ASp.net and dont know exactly how to use these code snippets.Amandeep Singh