# How do I play a sound in an asp.net web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to play some sounds in my web page once I click a button. This is my code but it shows an error.

```
SoundPlayer x = new SoundPlayer();
x.SoundLocation = "WindowsBalloon.wav";
//x.Play();
x.PlaySync();
```

error:

> Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location.

but the file exists in my project and I'm sure that the address is correct.

Comment: `"WindowsBalloon.wav"` is a relative path, make it absolute `"c:\\WindowsBalloon.wav"`.where do you expect to hear the sound? on the server or the client.your example will play the sound on the server.

Answer (score 12):

**You cannot play a file on a web page using the [System.Media.Soundplayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class !!!**

### Reason

It will play sound on server-side not client-side.

As mentioned as in below links
- [Problem With The C# System.Media.SoundPlayer Class On A Web Host](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27846-problem-with-the-c%23-systemmediasoundplayer-class-on-a-web-host/)
- [What is the most “compatible” way of autoplaying sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775832/what-is-the-most-compatible-way-of-autoplaying-sound/5775984#5775984) ?

### Solution

- Other [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775984/468718) over this same requirements.
- Use Any other Flash or Silverlight based plugins.
- Use html embed tag or html5 audio tag. Examples can be seen on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp)

### Html5-based audio solutions (works on modern browsers only)

- `<embed>` tag: The `<embed>` tag defines a container for external (non-HTML) content. (It is an HTML5  tag, invalid in HTML 4, but works in all browsers).

```html
<embed height="100" width="100" src="horse.mp3" />
```

- `<object>` tag: The `<object>` tag can also define a container for external (non-HTML) content.

```html
<object height="100" width="100" data="horse.mp3"></object>
```

- `<audio>` tag: The `<audio>` element is an HTML5 element, invalid in HTML 4, but it works in all browsers.

```html
<audio controls="controls" height="100" width="100">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <embed height="100" width="100" src="horse.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Please note the problems with html5-based solutions you must convert your videos to different formats.
- The `<audio>` element does not validate as HTML 4 and XHTML.
- The `<embed>` element does not validate as HTML 4 and XHTML.
- The `<embed>` element cannot "fall-back" to display an error.

Comment: How to play a beep sound on BUTTON CLICK? all answers here didn't help?

Comment: Its better to ask your question separately if any existing question doesn't cover your scenario.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/object) or  `<embed>` html tags.

```
<object data="WindowsBalloon.wav"></object>
```

Or HTML5  tag

```
<audio src="WindowsBalloon.wav">
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: What about non HTML5 browsers like IE8? is flash the only option then?

Answer (score 2):

This works in `HTML5` :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<embed height='0' width='0' src='Sound.wav' />");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you want:

```
Server.MapPath(string path);
```

Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.

Parameters: path: The virtual path of the Web server.
Returns: The physical file path that corresponds to path.

```
SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer();<br>
s.SoundLocation = **Server.MapPath("WindowsBalloon.wav");**<br>
s.PlaySync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given full path i.e. `c:\wavfiles\WindowsBalloon.wav`

'wavfiles' above is a user privileged folder.

```
use x.PlayLooping()
```

function if you want to play sound file continuously

BE CAREFUL!

use one button to exit loop else sound file will run continuously. I suggest you to exit the loop: -

**Code**

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        x.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to play an ALARM sound programmatically you can do it this way:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panBuzz" style="visibility:hidden">
   <audio runat="server" id="Buzz"  src="http://.....mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code behind (visual basic):**

```
Dim cBuzz As HtmlControl = DirectCast(panBuzz.FindControl("Buzz"), HtmlControl)
cBuzz.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay")
```

**Code behind (C#):**

```
HtmlControl cBuzz = (HtmlControl)panBuzz.FindControl("Buzz");
cBuzz.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "autoplay");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here in 2024, a few things worked for me, but only one way would work across Firefox, Chrome and Edge. If you need to play an audio file from codebehind from Asp.Net.

1. Make it work from Javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play

```
<audio id="myAudio">
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.

```
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
x.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

2. In your codebehind, use a version of registering a startup script that fires the javascript from code behind.

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "sound", "javascript: playAudio(); ", true);

**Note:** There are several ways to fire javascript from codebehind. The above method will work if you have update panels on the page. If you don't, one of the other methods may work for you.

Several ways of playing audio from a web page worked in Chrome and Edge every time. This was the only method I found that worked with Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

try adding the drive letter to the path, such as "C:/WindowsBalloon.wav". But this would not play it on the client side. I would recomend trying HTML5 for the client side.

Answer (score -4):

SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer();
            s.SoundLocation = **Server.MapPath("WindowsBalloon.wav");**
            s.PlaySync();

Comment: Please, add explanation about your solution and format your code.