# No Printers are installed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing

I have completed my mini-project of printing a text file in asp.net.
The project works well while I run it in my computer.
But when I upload it, and then press the print button on my website, the error page is displayed saying that No Printers are installed.
Actually I don't have any printers installed but I use Microsoft XPS Document Writer as a default printer.
Why I am getting this error?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing the client and the server.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know more about clients and servers. I am a newbie.

Comment: Your ASP.Net code runs on _server_, which is not the same computer that the user is using. the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server

Comment: Did you mean I need to install the drivers for printer on the web server?

Comment: If I have another computer on which some printer is installed then will I get the print?

Comment: The pages runs and lives on the server, where iis exist. What you see with your client is on your PC. When you call programmatically the printer, you done on code behind on server (not on your pc). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342519/how-to-play-sound-by-clicking-button-in-asp-net/12342639#12342639

Comment: @user2284240: No; I mean that your code is impossible.  Your server-side code cannot access printers on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and it turned out to be that the windows account used by the website's application pool didn't have access to the printers.