# How to upload and play audio file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have web form ,in which when user click a button and select file from local   device and upload it to folder that is in my project now,then this file pass audio   tag of html5,and ready to play
i tried following code

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
 <asp:Button ID="btnbrowse" runat="server" Text="Upload File"
 CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block"
  OnClick="btnbrowse_Click" />
 </div>
```

and code behind

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName);
if (fileName != null)
{
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Forms/Upload/" + fileName));
    string PATH = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Forms/Upload"), FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName);
    string Path = Server.MapPath(FileUpload5.FileName);
    SoundPlayer playthewavfile = new SoundPlayer(PATH);
    playthewavfile.SoundLocation = Path.ToString();
    playthewavfile.SoundLocation = PATH.ToString();
    playthewavfile.Play();               
}
```

Comment: {"The file located at G:\\backup\\LTM.CTP.WEBFORM\\LTM.CTP.WEBFORM\\Forms\\Upload\\q1.wav is not a valid wave file."}

Comment: *Is* it a valid file then? Could you play the original? Is it the uploaded file the same size as the original?

Comment: you are right ,this file is just empty file,then how  i can solve this

Comment: how can i save it in db then return it again to play it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I played the `.wav` file, I first saved the `.wav` file then passed that `.wav` file to the `SoundPlayer` class object to play the file.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads/"), FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer(path);
s.Play();
```

Please notice, this might not work for audio formats other than `.wav`, see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) from Microsoft.

> The SoundPlayer class cannot play other file types, such as .wma or
> .mp3. If you want to play other file types, you can use the Windows
> Media Player control. For more information, see Using the Windows
> Media Player Control in a .NET Framework Solution and Windows Media
> Player Object Model Reference for Visual Basic .NET and C# in the
> Windows Media Player SDK.

Plus, I would not suggest the server side code to play audio because the audio might just run on the server and client may have no idea if something is being played or not. It is highly recommended that you use html audio player and pass the path to it. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12329272/4308286) for a reference.

Comment: File is uploaded ,but this is an empty file of that file which i have uploaded

Comment: bro, try testing your code on a newly created web page, further more, can you tell me why you are writing these line of codes?    string Path = Server.MapPath(FileUpload5.FileName);    and    playthewavfile.SoundLocation = Path.ToString();

Comment: i thought that there is my location of file that cause exception,but when i debug i found that file is uploaded but this just an empty file that cause exception?how i can do this if i save this file in db then get back to play it? or directly pass upload file to play?

Comment: bro, before/after saving the file in some specific location, save it's path in the Database so that you can get the file directly by just reading the path from database